# How do I run the Fancytree jQuery plugin in a Chrome extension with strict Content Security Policy directives?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, fancytree

I am trying to run a local version of the Fancytree jQuery plugin, installed with Yarn and imported with Webpack, in a webpage loaded as a Chrome extension.

Chrome throws two errors of the form:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the
> 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-[...]'), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that
> 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
> fallback.

The first error is caused by a call to the insertBySelector function (at the line calling .appendChild()):

```
function insertBySelector(insert, style) {
  var target = getTarget(insert);

  if (!target) {
    throw new Error("Couldn't find a style target. This probably means that the value for the 'insert' parameter is invalid.");
  }

  target.appendChild(style);
}
```

The second one by a call to the styleTagTransform function (also at the line calling .appendChild()):

```
function styleTagTransform(css, styleElement) {
  if (styleElement.styleSheet) {
    styleElement.styleSheet.cssText = css;
  } else {
    while (styleElement.firstChild) {
      styleElement.removeChild(styleElement.firstChild);
    }

    styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  }
}
```

How can I solve this issue without relaxing the CSP directives?
Do I need to modify the Fancytree plugin? If so, in which way?
Do I have other options?

Comment: Pages with `chrome-extension://` URL can certainly use inline styles by default, no need to do anything special, so maybe you've modified CSP yourself in manifest.json or by adding a meta element in html or it's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm You're right, a novice's mistake. With that said, I intend to inject a content script into external webpages to display my tree in a side panel. Will I not run into the same problem at that time? How would I need to deal with it?

Comment: You can place the UI inside an iframe exposed via `web_accessible_resources`. Inside the iframe you'll have a full extension page. If this is not an option, you'll have to use a different styling framework that doesn't rely on inline styles.